# Displaying image using jQuery and Json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a database which contains the HTML Source for the image. Using jQuery and Json; I want to display the image. Here is the snippet I have written for it,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#domainID").click(function() {
            var domain_id = $(this).val();
            $("#picture").html('');
            $.getJSON('/index.php/admin/show_picture/' + domain_id, function(data) {
                img = "<img src=\"https://url/" + data.htmlImageFull + "\" />";
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $("#picture").append(data[key].htmlImageFull);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

The main thing is I will be retrieving the html source using the ID of the image associated with it. Any changes I have to make here? I am also using MySQL to check the id associated with the image.

and Here is the HTML,

```
<form method="post" action="/index.php/add">
    <p>
        <select name="id" id="id" size="15">
            <option>Select a Domain</option>
            <? foreach ($unmatchedDomains as $row) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->domain
                ?></option>
            <? }?>
        </select>
        </td>
        <select name="id" id="id">
            <option style="alignment-adjust: &#x2190;">Select Something</option>
            <? foreach ($some as $row) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?=$row->id?>"><?=$row->name
                ?></option>
            <? }?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Something" />
        <div id="email_content"></div>
        <div id="picture"></div>
    </p>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Testing with the provided code shows no picture/image.

Comment: you're not appending `img` to something.

Comment: is this a real question?

Comment: Well, why do you ask? Why not just test it? Is this not working? Does it give errors? How does your HTML look? What is #picture? Is that an img? (hope not)

Comment: @SinistraD I have tested it and It does not show anything.

Comment: Good to know. Now edit your question, add this information to it, also the answers to my other questions. Thanks

Comment: @SinistraD well, #picture is an image.

Comment: #picture is an image? that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the img tag to the picture element.

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $("#picture").append("<img src=\"https://url/" + data[key].htmlImageFull + "\" />");
});
```